# Unhandled exception when using VB arithmetic operators

Tags: vb.net, math

I have a function that loops through a list of servers, and then for each carries out a number of functions.

At the beginning each iteration, I need to calculate which 'step' the process is currently at (so that a progress bar can be updated correctly), but this line is causing an error -

```
Me.CurrentStepLoop = ((Me.CurrentServerLoop - 1) * Me.ServerSteps) + 1
```

All three of the referenced properties are integers, and the values are quite low (I.e `CurrentServerLoop` has a maximum of 6 and `ServerSteps` has a maximum of 20, so`CurrentStepLoop` can be no more that 101 from this equation.

Here is the error that I am getting -

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I find it particularly odd that I have the line in question within a `Try...Catch`, yet the error is not handled by my code and instead I see generic Visual Exchange error. The line is not actually highlighted, but I know it is that as if I comment it out the error does not occur

Can anybody shed some light on why this may be happening? Thanks.

Here is the snippit that I believe is causing the issue, as well as a [link to the full code](http://pastebin.com/NBpHeXNv) -

```
For Each CurrentServer In Me.Servers

    If bw.CancellationPending = True Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit For
    Else

        Try
            Me.CurrentStepLoop = ((Me.CurrentServerLoop - 1) * Me.ServerSteps) + 1
        Catch Ex As Exception
            Dim ErrorForm As New formError(Ex)
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End Try

        MappingResult = Me.DoMapDrives(CurrentServer)
        If Not MappingResult Then bw.CancelAsync() : Exit For

        {...Other actions here...}

        CurrentServerLoop += 1

    End If

Next
```

Comment: You could add a handler for the unhandled exception to your code.  For example, add `AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf HandleUnhandledExceptionEvent` to your Form load (or equivalent entry point) method and then interrogate the exception within that exception handler to get more info on what is going on.  Wacky, indeed.

Comment: This error is not provoked by the type, but by the given variables and how you are accessing them. Please, include the code where all the variables are declared and further issues which should be known (e.g., using multiple threads).

Comment: @varocarbas - I won't include the whole code at this stage (it's quite sizable), but I can tell you that the sample in the question comes from the `bw_DoWork()` function, and thus the calls above are occurring in a `BackgroundWorker`. Also, the `BackgroundWorker` runs on a form and the properties in question are declared on that form. Please let me know if you want more info...

Comment: Is `CurrentStepLoop` a variable or a property? If it's a property, does the setter do anything else, e.g. raise an event? Same question for the getters of `CurrentServerLoop´ and `ServerSteps`.

Comment: @Nico Schertler - All are properties and the getters/setters do nothing but set the values. Thanks.

Comment: Set the values where? In variables? In properties of controls?

Comment: I'm fairly new to .NET and I'm not 100% what you mean by all of the above. I've placed the full code for the form on which the error occurs in a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NBpHeXNv), and I'd be grateful if you could take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error and why it occurred.

In the method `SetSteps()` I calculate `Me.StepSize`, but I was doing so incorrectly. Changing this -

```
Me.StepSize = Me.proProgress.Maximum / Me.ServerSteps
```

To this solved the problem -

```
Me.StepSize = Me.proProgress.Maximum / Me.TotalSteps
```

The issue was that the Progress bar was being set passed it's maximum, which caused the error. Thanks.